# How do I toggle the contents of an input filed to be encrypted and non encrypted in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input field and I want the contents to read 'ab****gh' and be able to toggle the contents with a click to read 'abcdefgh'.  Basically a reveal and not reveal.  I'm having trouble making the value reactive when I change it.  Below is some partial code that I've been working with.

Basically i'm trying to swap the content of the input with the encrypted value

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
regex_hide_characters: /(?<!^).(?!$)/g,
inputValue: this.value,
encryptedInputValue: this.value.replace(this.regex_hide_characters, '*'),

hidePrivateContent() {
    this.reveal = !this.reveal;
    if (!this.reveal) {
        this.$refs.input.value = this.encryptedInputValue;
     }
},
```

Comment: change the type of the field from `password` to `text`

Comment: But won't that encrypt all of the value?  Or Can I set it to format like this, 123*******

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I've added an example of what you're looking for below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic sample of how you'd achieve something like this:

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 computed: {
  hiddenPass() {
    if (this.isPass) return this.pass.slice(0, 2) + '*******';
    return this.pass;
  }
 },
 data() {
  return {
    isPass: true,
    pass: 'abc124defg'
  }
 },
 methods: {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <div>{{hiddenPass}}</div>
  <button @click="isPass=!isPass">toggle view</button>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I'm taking advantage of [`computed properties`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) in order to determine, based on data on the instance, how to show the "protected" pass.

I hope this helps!

Comment: wow, that's fantastic, and so simple!  I'll give that a try, thanks so much!

Comment: @DonegalBoyVancouver any update? did this work for you

Comment: yep, that worked out, sorry I stepped out for a bit.   Thanks for the help man!